# composer require finished, but I cant't see the package folder

Tags: laravel, composer-php

Where does the package files go? I ran `composer require clarifysky/administrator` successfully, but I cant't find the package in my vendor directory.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This package is listed on packigist as a metapackage. From the [composer docs](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#type)

> **metapackage:** An empty package that contains requirements and will trigger their installation, but contains no files and will not write anything to the filesystem. As such, it does not require a dist or source key to be installable.